# How do large companies like Google store their logs so the information is accessible and useful?

Tags: logging

I'm sure Google generates petabytes of log information from their systems, how is it stored and made useful (I guess searchable)? Do they have like processes that copy the log data to some centralized database? And how do they minimize any impact from these processes on production systems?

Reason I'd like to know is because I am trying to implement some process to download the logs from our PROD box, then normalize and store it in mongodb on another UAT/non-PROD server. That way it is queryable and we can generate analytics from the data. Production Support won't allow us to connect from UAT to PROD to download the raw logs.

I think if our apps stored directly in the (remote) mongo instance it would have huge impact on the servers' performance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer for Google. But do have an opinion about rolling your own log management system. Getting logs from some things are much more difficult than others and you will have varying degrees of success trying to roll your own.

For example, application logs should really come out of the application's logging frameworks so that more details can be caught like errors, context variables, web request info and more. Most of this data is never found in a simple text file being logged to disk.

Most commercial log management products don't even do a good job of tracking application errors to uniquely identify them so they can be tracked and resolved. Stackify (http://stackify.com) is the only product I know of that does this while at the same time doing log management. They are usually separate tools.
Other tools that you may be interested in looking at LogEntries, Loggly and the like (though as mentioned they do only the log piece)

Getting app logs from apps that consonantly deploy to new servers or scale up and down creates unique challenges as well.